# Error in writting xml : "error on line 3 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document"

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

here the c# code I use to respond xml data

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;

public partial class xmlData : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.ContentType = "text/xml"; 
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>"+
                     "<note>"+
                         "<to>Tove</to>"+
                         "<from>Jani</from>"+
                         "<heading>Reminder</heading>"+
                         "<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>"+
                      "</note>";

        Response.Write(xml);

    }
}
```

but I got this error .. why ?

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 3 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [`Response.End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) to stop the rest of the page from being rendered after your XML - or preferrably, don't have this as a "page" in the first place. It's not *really* a page, after all - it's just some XML. It sounds like you really want a "handler" (ASHX file and a class implementing [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx)) instead, which isn't going to automatically add any content for you.